# How does pip make a package execuable?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

After installing [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) with `sudo pip install fabric` on Ubuntu 14.04, I can use `fab` command in console, which is actually a executable script "/usr/local/bin/fab".

As far as I know, `sudo pip install` will put a package under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, and I didn't find some copy operation in [fabric/setup.py](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/setup.py) to put the script "fab" into "/usr/local/bin".

So how and when `sudo pip install fabric` put file "fab" into "/usr/local/bin"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip` doesn't do this, the package `setup.py` does (via the [`setuptools` library](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest)). All `pip` does is locate the package, download it and run `python setup.py install` in that package to install it.

`setuptools` has a [concept of *entry points*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins), arbitrary configuration to plug in to Python code looking for these. One such entry point is the `console_scripts` entry point, which names commands and the Python module plus function used to run them. The [`setup.py` file for Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/setup.py#L50-L54) has this:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'fab = fabric.main:main',
    ]
},
```

This tells `setuptools` to create a `fab` command that'll run the `main()` function in the `fabric.main` module when you invoke it.

See the [*Automatic Script Creation* section](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in the `setuptools` documentation.

Comment: [Automatic Script Creation section](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) doesn't mention where to put the console scripts.
So the "/usr/loca/bin" is defined in setuptools and can't be configured by package developers, is it right?

Comment: @Chad: it is defined by the `sys.exec_prefx`, IIRC, the location you installed the `python` binary into.

Comment: @Chad: you can always create a virtualenv and install Fabric into that; then the virtualenv `bin/` path is used.

Comment: @Chad: but no, *package developers* can't state where the console scripts are installed, no.